# Java How to print -1 if the given letter1 is not present

Tags: java, string, indexing, numbers, character

I would like to write a program that is taking letter position from two strings, string1 and string2, then it will check where in string2 we have the same letters used but also print number of indexes and if there is no letter that is in the first string just print -1 . For example I have first string = "reds" second one = "Hello world!", then my output should be:
r: 8, e: 1, d: 10, s: -1

Here is my code:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String set1 = "reds";
        String set2 = "Hello world!";
        for(int i = 0; i < set1.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < set2.length();j++)
            {
            char currentChar = set1.charAt(i);
            char currentChar2 = set2.charAt(j);
            if(currentChar == currentChar2)
                {
                System.out.println(currentChar+": "+j);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another ways using `String.indexOf`

Classic for loop

```
String set1 = "reds";
String set2 = "Hello world!";
for(int i = 0; i < set1.length(); i++){
    System.out.println(set1.charAt(i) + " : " + set2.indexOf(set1.charAt(i)));
}
```

or streams

```
set1.chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char)c + " : " + set2.indexOf(c))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note: if the chars apear more than once in the second string the first index of the chars is printed (use `lastIndexOf` if you want the last index)

Answer (score 1):

```
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String set1 = "reds";
    String set2 = "Hello world!";
    for(int i = 0; i < set1.length(); i++) {        
        char currentChar = set1.charAt(i);
        boolean found = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < set2.length();j++) {            
            char currentChar2 = set2.charAt(j);
            if(currentChar == currentChar2) {                
                System.out.println(currentChar+": "+j);
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!found) {
            System.out.println(currentChar + ": -1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I knew it was easy, I am so silly. If anybody has also any another solution I will appreciate every answer <3

Answer (score 0):

It will print every position of the set1 characters into set2.

O(n + m) time complexity, where n and m are the sizes of set1 and set2

O(256) space complexity because of ASCII numbers

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String set1 = "reds";
    String set2 = "Hello world!";

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();  // key = ascii value of the char, value = list of indexes

    for(int i = 0; i < set2.length(); i++){
        int key = set2.charAt(i);

        if(!map.containsKey(key)){
            map.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
        }

        List<Integer> indexesList = map.get(key);
        indexesList.add(i);
        map.put(key, indexesList);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < set1.length(); i++){
        int key = set1.charAt(i);

        System.out.print(set1.charAt(i) + ": ");

        if(!map.containsKey(key)){
            System.out.println(-1);
        }
        else {
            map.get(key).forEach(x-> System.out.print(x+ " "));
            System.out.println(); // just for new line
        }
    }
}
```